# Lost 30 lbs in 6-8 months. But need to bring down fat percentage

Tags: weight-loss, abdominals, body-fat

I am 5'10''. I weighed 193 lbs last May, now I have reduced to 164 pounds(stalling at the same weight for over 2 months) with 23% of body fat. I need to get rid of those and bring down my weight for 154, which is the cut-off for being fit for my height. I lift weights. I do legs, but I still feel my butt is kinda out of shape, my tummy has a flab(it is kinda flat though), my chest is not exactly ripped(if I don't do chest for 3-4 days, it kinda pushes out in an awkward shape). I need to fix all these(am planning with in Feb). I can do push ups but not pull ups. Since I am stalling with the same weight for too many days, I know I have change something. Right now I do weights about 3-4 days a week, alternating lower body(squats,deadlifts, kettle bell swings), upper body(SMP, pushups, shoulder, bicepts curl(25lbs)). I need to fix my body fat, tighten my butt, flat abs, curl my shoulders more. Am I doing anything wrong, would you change something on what I am dng to achieve wat I want. The trainer at the gym insists that I do the same thing, but I think I need to change something. I know there would be lots of similar threads and sorry for custom posting.

Comment: Are you male or female?

Comment: What are your squat, bench, deadlift and overhead press numbers?  If you are a male, I can assure you that 154 at your height is a lot smaller than the cutoff for being fit.  This is the middle of what the BMI calls normal weight, but 180 at 10% body fat should be acheivable naturally.  Check out http://www.naturalphysiques.com/28/fat-free-mass-index-ffmi

Comment: How are you measuring body fat?  23% @ 5'10"/164lbs Male sounds very high, unless you have quite a small frame.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at what you are eating, and get real with yourself about it.  If you have to, track everything until you really know what you are eating.

- Protein should be up around 1g / lb lean body weight, preferably from lean meats
- You should be eating plenty of fibrous vegetables
- You should be getting roughly 1/3 of your calories from of healthy dietary fats (organic butter, coconut oil, olive oil, fat in organic meat, nuts, etc.)
- The remainder of your calories should be in the form of high fiber carb sources like brown rice, sweet potatoes, potatoes, etc.
- Calm your sweet tooth with whole fruit (not juices)

The types of things you should be avoiding include sugar, trans fats, and foods high in manufactured food substitutes (like hamburger helper).

Exercise is great, but you will do better if you don't count the Calories you expend against what you eat.  For example, if some chart says you've burned 500 Calories from your exercise resist the temptation to eat 500 Calories more of anything.

> *If your current diet includes trips to fast food restaurants, chances are you are consuming far more Calories than you realize.*

At some point, in order to keep progressing in cutting fat you will have to reduce your Calorie intake further.

Also note, how you track body fat may be part of the problem.  One example is the bioimpedance scale which is an [approximation built on an approximation](http://weightology.net/weightologyweekly/?page_id=218) which is not only inaccurate it is even worse when used for tracking change over time (by +/- 8%).  You might have lost fat and the bio impedance scale registers no change.  Part of the problem is how the scale takes its measurements and ignores subcutaneous fat.  Tape measures and simple weight measurements give a better overall picture of progress.

It doesn't hurt to have some low intensity steady state (LISS) cardio work in your routine.  Not only is there benefit with burning a few more calories, it also can help you recover from your exercise a little quicker and sleep better by lowering your resting heart rate.  Sleep is very important in any weight loss or muscle building endeavor.